# Need to get success ratio for clients

Tags: sql, postgresql, integer, aggregate-functions, numeric

I had a really nice guy in FreeNode IRC steer me closer to the answer.

The query I am using now is:

```
SELECT st.staff_id
     , ROUND (100.0 * ( sum (case when s.code in ('10401','10402','10403') then 1
                                      else 0 end)/count(s.code)), 1) as successes
    from notes n join services s on n.zrud_service=s.zzud_service
            join staff st on n.zrud_staff = st.zzud_staff
    WHERE s.code IN ( '10401','10402','10403','10405')
    AND n.date_service BETWEEN (now() - '30 days'::interval)::timestamp AND now()
    group by st.staff_id;
```

(I did try /count(*) as well as a few other ways)

It does not error, and shows the results as either 100.0 or 0
I ran a query on just the codes grouped by staff and get different results.  One staff discharged 23 people in the past month, 8 being unsuccessful (10405)  This gives a percentage of 34.7% success rate.  But the query shows 0%.

This is baffling.  Anyone have suggestions?

#### Original question

I need to be able to see what percentage of successful discharges there are in a 30 day period.  Here is a query that shows the discharges by code.  I understand that I can use a "division" method in postgresql, but I have only been able to use it with two separate columns.  Can someone assist in showing me how to divide data within a column?
I need to do something like: 10401'+'10402'+'10403' / 10401'+'10402'+'10403'+'10405'

```
SELECT n.date_creation, g.name AS Group, s.staff_id, n.date_service, c.client_id,
       c.name_lastfirst_cs AS Client, q.code 
FROM notes n, clients c, groups g, staff s,services q 
WHERE n.visibility_flag = 1 -- valid note
AND notes.date_service BETWEEN (now() - '30 days'::interval)::timestamp AND now();
AND c.zzud_client = n.zrud_client AND n.zrud_group = g.zzud_group  
AND n.zrud_staff = s.zzud_staff 
AND q.code IN ('10401','10402','10403','10405')  -- 10405 is unsuccessful discharge
AND n.zrud_service = q.zzud_service AND n.zrud_staff = ? ORDER BY n.date_service
```

If I re-write the query as such:

```
SELECT g.name AS Group, s.staff_id, c.client_id,
       c.name_lastfirst_cs AS Client, q.code 
FROM notes n, clients c, groups g, staff s,services q 
WHERE n.visibility_flag = 1 -- valid note
AND notes.date_service BETWEEN (now() - '30 days'::interval)::timestamp AND now();
AND c.zzud_client = n.zrud_client AND n.zrud_group = g.zzud_group  
AND n.zrud_staff = s.zzud_staff 
AND n.zrud_service = q.zzud_service AND n.zrud_staff = ? ORDER BY n.date_service
```

OR, Instead of all the +'s, could I use the "SUM" operator?

I changed the query to:

```
SELECT g.name AS Group, s.staff_id AS Staff
SUM(CASE WHEN q.code BETWEEN '10401' AND '10405' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN q.code       BETWEEN '10401' AND '10405' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
 AS success_ratio FROM FROM notes n, clients c, groups g, staff s,services q  
 AND n.date_service BETWEEN (now() - '30 days'::interval)::timestamp AND now()
AND q.code IN ('10401','10402','10403','10405')
AND c.zzud_client = n.zrud_client AND n.zrud_group = g.zzud_group  
AND n.zrud_staff = s.zzud_staff 
AND n.zrud_service = q.zzud_service AND s.staff_id = 'BATTNEAL1026' ORDER BY n.date_service
 GROUP BY s.staff_id
```

And get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SUM"
> LINE 2: SUM(CASE WHEN q.code BETWEEN '10401' AND '10405' THEN 1 ELSE...
>         ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "SUM"
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 45
> ```

Comment: How will you identify that a client is discharged successfully, any where u save it..??

Comment: Shahid,  This is the rub!  I need to count up all discharges (10401,10402,10403,10405) create in the query two columns such as

Comment: Shahid,  This is the rub!  I need to count up all discharges (10401,10402,10403,10405) put that sum into one column "ALL" and put sum of 10405 into another column "DISC" then divide DISC by ALL to get success rate, placing that into another column 'SUCCESS"

Comment: Please clean up the mess. Remove irrelevant information and [use proper format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the division with two `bigint` / `integer` numbers. Since your result is always < 0, this results in either 0 or 1. Here:

```
sum (case when s.code in ('10401','10402','10403') then 1 else 0 end)
    /count(s.code)
```

**Multiply by `100.0` first.**
The fractional digit in `100.0` coerces the calculation to be done in `numeric`, which preserves the fractional part.

With some other modifications and formatting, it could look like this:

```
SELECT st.staff_id
      ,round((count(s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403') OR NULL) * 100.0)
            / count(*), 1) AS successes
FROM   notes    n 
JOIN   services s  ON s.zzud_service = n.zrud_service
JOIN   staff    st ON st.zzud_staff = n.zrud_staff
WHERE  s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403','10405')
AND    n.date_service BETWEEN (now() - '30 days'::interval) AND now()
GROUP  BY st.staff_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance!  I think I understand it, but will read on each element to make sure.  Bottom line is the query works now. Before, I was getting results of 100% or 0.  It would really be great if I could find a book that taught postgresql skills in a practical way, each level of query building on the former.  That would not only give me a better skill set, but I could also assist others when I can explain the "how's and why's" a query works.   Thanks again